# How to Convert Decimal to Binary in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, masm, x86-16

Im having trouble analyzing this block of code in converting decimal values to binary. Can somebody help explain the lines of text below? This is a working code by the way. I would really appreciate the help, this is for studying purposes. Thanks you!

```
calc :
    mul multiplier
    mov bl, byte ptr [si]
    mov bh, 00h
    add ax, bx
    inc si
    loop calc

    mov si, offset buf4 + 2
    mov bx, ax
    mov dx, 0000h
    mov ax, 8000h
convert :
    mov cx, 0000h
conv :
    cmp bx, ax
    jb cont3
    sub bx, ax
    inc cx
    jmp conv
cont3 :
    add cl, 30h
    mov byte ptr [si], cl
    inc si
    mov cx, 0002h
    div cx
    cmp ax, 0000h
    jnz convert

    mov byte ptr [si], '$'
    prnstr buf3
    prnstr buf4+2
stop :
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
```

The first part of the code was no trouble to understand (Accepting user input and checking if its a valid decimal number). I already added some comments.. the first half of the code looks like this:

```
prnstr macro msg     ;acts like a function to print string
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, msg
    int 21h
    endm

data segment
    buf1 db "Enter a decimal number : $"
    buf2 db 0ah, "Invalid Decimal Number...$"
    buf3 db 0ah, "Equivalent Binary number is : $"
    buf4 db 6
         db 0
         db 6 dup(0)
    multiplier db 0ah
data ends

code segment
    assume cs:code, ds:data
    start :
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov es, ax   

    prnstr buf1         ;Display

    mov ah, 0ah         ;Get line function
    lea dx, buf4        ;adress of input buffer
    int 21h

    mov si, offset buf1 + 2 ;Load pointer to beginning of structure
    mov cl, byte ptr [si-1] ;determine end of loop?
    mov ch, 00h
    subtract :
    mov al, byte ptr [si]   ;Load 1 byte of buf1 to cl
    cmp al, 30h             ;check if not below 0
    jnb cont1

    jmp stop
 cont1 :
    cmp al, 3ah         ;check if not above 9
    jb cont2
    prnstr buf2         ;Display
    jmp stop
 cont2 :
    sub al, 30h             ;convert ASCII to Decimal number
    mov byte ptr [si], al   ;place bcd form back to pointed character
    prnstr buf2             ;Display
    inc si                  ;next character
    loop subtract           ;repeat until end of string
    mov si, offset buf1 + 2 ;Load pointer to beginning of structure
    mov cl, byte ptr [si-1] ;reset to determine end of loop using si
    mov ch, 00h
    mov ax, 0000h           ;reset ax to 0

    ;...CONTINUE TO calc.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `calc:` loop keeps multiplying by 10 and accumulating, so it appears that it calculates the actual value of the number that was entered in decimal.  (It converts the string you entered, say "42", to the number 42.)

The remaining code converts the number that was calculated to binary.  It is written in a kind of unorthodox way, to say the least.

The instruction `mov dx, 0000h` clears `dx`, because further down the `div cx` instruction divides the `dx:ax` pair by `cx`, so if `dx` was not zero then you would get garbage.

The `ax` register starts with the value `08000h` which in binary is a `1` followed by 15 `0`s and in each iteration of the loop it keeps being divided by 2, so on each iteration a new binary digit of `0` enters in from the left side, the `1` binary digit is moved to the right by one position, and a `0` binary digit drops out from the right side.

The check for `ax` against zero will stop looping when the `1` binary digit drops out after 16 iterations, leaving `ax` with all zeros.

The `conv:` loop is a very unorthodox way of setting `cx` to `0` or `1` depending on whether the bit represented by `ax` is set or cleared in `bx`. This loop loops at most once, so I think that the `jmp conv` instruction could be missing, and it could just fell through to the `cont2:` label.

Also note that loading `2` into `cx` and then executing `div cx` is retarded, you can just `shr ax, 1`.

Comment: `div` instead of a simple shift is really silly, but this code is full of inefficiency.  e.g. the `mov bh,0` in the `calc` loop could be hoisted out of the loop and replaced with `xor bx,bx` to maybe avoid partial-register stalls.  And there are spare registers, so using a memory source operand for `mul` is very silly, especially if tuning for an old CPU without cache.  It's using the slow `loop` instruction, so it's obviously not tuned for anything recent.  And not for small code-size.  (But avoiding instructions like `movzx` or `imul ax, cx, 10` that later CPUs introduced :/)

Comment: TL:DR: this code is pretty crap all over the place; probably written by a novice.

Comment: @PeterCordes ssssh, don't tell anyone, but professors are often novices when it comes to actually coding something.

Comment: My favourite part is a macro called `prnstr`.  I can't help but read that as "porn-star" in my head.  And BTW, good people can write bad code; I'm not saying the author is stupid, merely inexperienced.  (And/or just writing something that works, without even trying to choose a *good* way to implement things.  I'd consider this a mistake in asm, because there's no compiler to turn your semantics into good code.  If you aren't even trying to optimize for *something*, asm is the wrong language for almost everything.)

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot!